# third central moment negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

Let $X$ be negative binomial distributed with parameter $p$ and $r$.

Show that:

$1$) $E$($X$) = $r$ $\cdot$ $\frac{q}{p}$

$2$) $Var$($X$) = $r$ $\cdot$ $\frac{q}{q^2}$

$3$) Calculate the third central moment.
So I have to calculate $E$(($X$ - $E$($X$))${^3}$).

I was able to calculate $1$) and $2$). But I have no idea how to calculate $3$).